# Using Moles with System.Reflection

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moles

I'm trying to mole the method Assembly.GetEntryAssembly but it appears that 
only stub types are generated for the System.Reflection namespace i.e. 
System.Reflection.Moles.SAssembly is generated but not System.Reflection.Moles.MAssembly.

I checked and another namespace System.Resource has both the stub and runtime mole types e.g. both System.Resources.Moles.SIResourceWriter and System.Resources.Moles.MResourceWriter are available.

Any knowledge about this specific issue would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/c262d8f1-246e-4157-a7b4-f7ddeaf1890c/ for details.

Comment: Argh ... that's killing me ... :(